# Power Automate - extract number combination

Tags: office365, powerapps, power-automate

I have got problem with extracting number from subject in Power Automate.

Trigger is when new mail arrives, then i wanted to extract number in format '111.222' from subject.
Also don't know how to make condition true/false to check if subject contains this specific combination, something like "???.???" doesn't work.

Comment: Currently, you have more than one question here

Comment: Could you post screenshots of the trigger or the output from the trigger in JSON?